# Designing UI without Title bar

Tags: android, user-interface, styles, titlebar

This is the screenshot of the app UI which I'm designing which includes title bar.

[image: Screenshot of app UI]

If I remove the title bar with the following code:

```
<style name="ShaMounter" parent="android:Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"></style>
```

It becomes like this image:

[image: Collapsed]

I want the UI of the original image without titlebar. Could anyone help me?

Comment: I run this app in my Micromax Canvas 2 (A110)

Comment: did u mean full screen app? use this : <style name="ShaMounter" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></style>

Answer (score 0):

Those two themes you switch between, define defaults for whatever controls you use on the left side, differently. Thus leaving you with an only option of specifying height and alignment manually in XML file of in your `styles.xml`, whichever you prefer.

Comment: NO no no.. I don't want full screen... I want the app without the titlebar.. it's working.. But when i'm setting to NoTitleBar the designing part get changed.. That means I wants to preserve the UI design as in First image i've included... Hardly it being get changed when i set NoTitleBar as shown in image two... I dont want the views modified

Comment: Now I see. The problem is that those two themes you switch between, define defaults for whatever controls you use on the left side, differently. Thus leaving you with an only option of specifying height and alignment manually in XML file of in your styles.xml, whichever you prefer.

Comment: thanks.. i did a mistake with a actual heights of the views.. so i defined it manually in the xml.. and everythings ok now.... thanks geeks